# Use android device as Server using hotspot

Tags: android

I am trying to build an app that communicates with other android devices.
I want the user to have the ability to host the game if they are not connected to the same network. Doing so any one user could host the game and others could join it.
How can I do that? Are there any good tutorials for that.

Answer (score 0):

Using sockets in Android is very much like using Sockets in Java. Sockets will create a way for your devices to talk to each other. You will have to be a little clever using them to account for some erroneous behavior. The gist of sockets is that dropping something into one socket's output stream puts it into the other socket's input stream. On a very basic level, that's everything you need.

For a fairly simple example of how sockets work, check out out [This Page](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/socket-core/android-socket-example/).